# Apache server 32 binaries vs 64 binaries? what's the difference

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, apache-httpd, 64bit

For Windows I used to download either 32 bit binaries from ASF site or 64 bit binaries from Apache lounge site (for no particular reason). So  - that was the way I new what version I have.

I've switched to Ubuntu (for educational purposes) and got used to compiling from source.

When I compile Apache server from source - what binaries do I get? 32? 64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling is the process of building binaries from source. The configure script and makefile will select what's appropriate for your system. (64-bit executable for a 64-bit system, 32-bit for 32-bit.)

And if you have a 64-bit system, there is probably some potential for improved performance in using 64-bit binaries. For some things it could be a huge boost; I'm guessing that for Apache it's not quite so big a deal, but I'm no expert there. It certainly won't *hurt*, though, to build the appropriate binaries, and I don't see why you'd ever bother to mess with the build process to get 32-bit binaries if you have a 64-bit system.

Comment: A 64-bit binary will typically use more memory (both because the code is bigger, and because some kinds of data are twice as big (while others are the same size)). How much more is wildly dependent on the application, I don't know in what ballpark Apache is. But as you say, typically you'd install a whole 32-bit system or a whole 64-bit system.